# Full calender drag event not working event date after one week days

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

I have trying to implement auto scheduling employee in each days. I have tried to drag on employee on other day.

But i have face the issue on employee dragging not working current day after one week days.

Any ideas about my code, which place i have wrong.

```js
full_calender = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,listWeek,listDay'
   },
   views: {
    listDay: { buttonText: 'List View' },
    listWeek: { buttonText: 'Week View' },
    month: { buttonText: 'Month View' },
   },
            defaultDate: default_date,
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventResourceEditable: true,
            /*select: function (start, end) {
                addSelectedEvent(start, end);
            },*/
            eventConstraint: {
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded goodness unfortunately
            },
            dragRevertDuration: 1000,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta,revertFunc) {
    //if (!confirm('Are you sure '+ event.title + ' Moved On  '+event.start.format())) {
     //updateDroppableEvent(event.id,event.start.format());
     var data = {
      'action_update_droppable_event' : 'yes',
      'event_id' : event.id,
      'move_date' : event.start.format(),
     };
     $.ajax({
      URL : '',
      method : 'POST',
      data : data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(res){
       if(res.status == 'success'){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event  );
       }else{
        alert(res.msg);
        revertFunc(); 
        //window.location.reload();
       }
      },
      error : function(res){
       //console.log(res); 
      }
     });
   },
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: base_url + 'admin_dashboard/render_current_events',
     //url: base_url + 'admin_dashboard/get_holiday_list',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        zone_id: '<?php echo $_REQUEST['zone_id'] ?>',
                        custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                    }
                }
            ],
   /* Delete Event */
   eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
    deleteSelectedEvent(calEvent);
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
                //$(".fc-event-container a").append("<span class='event_edit_popup'><i class='icon-eye-open'></i></span>");
//            events: base_url + 'admin_dashboard/get_holiday_list',
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have find the bug on full calendar, If body,html height is 100% so full calendar not work properly.